# OpenJPA - Transaction management is not available... (Fuse ESB)

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, jta, fuseesb

I'm having trouble with `RESOURCE_LOCAL` transaction type for JPA in Fuse ESB.

I also don't have a complete understanding of whether `JTA` or `RESOURCE_LOCAL` is better for me.

My persistence.xml :

```
<persistence-unit name="invoicePersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/invDataSource)</jta-data-source>
    <non-jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/invDataSource)</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>com.company.service.Invoice</class>
    <!-- etc... -->

</persistence-unit>
```

My beans in blueprint.xml :

```
<reference id="invDataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource" filter="(datasource.name=invDataSource)"/>

<bean id="invoiceDao" class="com.company.project.InvoiceDao">
    <jpa:context unitname="invoicePersistence" property="entityManager"/>
    <tx:transaction method="*" value="Required" />
</bean>
```

And my code :

```
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    entityManager.persist(a);
    entityManager.persist(b);

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

And the exception, using transaction-type `RESOURCE_LOCAL` in my persistence.xml:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction management is not available for container managed EntityManagers.
```

I also tried using transaction-type `JTA` in my persistence.xml but then I received `OptimisticLockException`.

I'm not sure which approach is better (RESOURCE_LOCAL or JTA) but the main thing is that in my code object `a` and `b` need to be persisted in a transaction (all or nothing).

I'm running in Fuse ESB (camel, cxf, etc).

Thanks for any tips or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is the answer.

Firstly, 2 nice links on [JPA Concepts](http://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html) and the [Aries JPA Container](http://aries.apache.org/modules/jpaproject.html)

**RESOURCE_LOCAL**

`transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"` is indeed *self-managed* persistence, and the code should be like this:

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

...

entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.persist(a);
entityManager.persist(b);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Using `entityManager.getTransaction()` and `entityManager.flush()` both caused exceptions, because I had specified `<jpa:context>`.

The correct way to do it is with `<jpa:unit>` and `EntityManagerFactory`.

```
<bean id="invoiceDao" class="com.company.project.InvoiceDao">
    <jpa:unit unitname="invoicePersistence" property="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

**JTA**

On the other hand `transaction-type="JTA"` is 'container-managed' persistence:

```
entityManager.persist(a);
entityManager.persist(b);
```

and it should be configured in blueprint with `<jpa:context>` and an `EntityManager`.